# In search result page, pagination is not showing up

Tags: 7, search, migrations

I have migrated a site from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7. I have rendered the search form in page.tpl.php as follows:

```
<?php
     $block = module_invoke('search','block_view','form');          
     print render($block['content']); 
?>
```

I am able to search, but pagination is missing in the search result page.

In the theme folder I have search-results.tpl.php and **search-results.tpl.php**.

In the search-results.tpl.php `<?php print $pager; ?>`  is available.

**If I change theme to default theme or core theme pagination is working fine.**

What is the issue over here which is causing not showing pagination links?

Comment: how many items must be displayed in pager settings and how many items are showed in your search result?

Comment: By default its ten.Its showing ten, but not showing pagination links.

Comment: Are the result items more then ten?

Comment: Yes there are more then ten

Comment: may be something went wrong when you migrated from v6... You can also create your own search by views module.

Comment: Did you try the following things in preprocess function? function themename_preprocess_search_results(&$variables) { $variables['pagination'] = render(theme('pager')); }

Comment: Yes tried but no luck still not showing up

Comment: my $pager variable is empty if print_r($pager)

Comment: can you check that other paginations are working properly, like views pager or admin tables pagers?...

Comment: Those are working fine. Its really wierd that search alone has tat issue

Comment: Also notice that views pagers or admin tables pagers are being displayed on admin theme (different theme than yours)...

Comment: Is your website fully indexed? If you go to this URL: mywebsite.com/admin/config/search/settings, you should see if it's 100% indexed.

Comment: yes it is fully indexed. Still no pagination.

Comment: Try print how many results are there it showed like ths Displaying 1 - 5 of 5 results but it has 10 search result nodes its rendering. But there are more results and its not showing pagination for those

Comment: Why don't you go for `views_embed_view('view_machine_name');`.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think that this will help you but do it like this:

```
// template.php
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  $search_box = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('search_form'));
  $variables['search_box'] = $search_box;
}
```

page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $search_box; ?>
```

according to this [discussion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10282/how-can-i-insert-search-box-in-page-tpl). You should not put your logic into tpl.